How to programmatically create or edit a dial-up incoming connection in Windows 10?
I'm trying to automate the setup of a dial-up connection between two systems in Windows 10. The client (caller) side is already handled; I've programmed the dialing process, phonebook entries, and modem initialization. On the server (callee) side, I need to automate the creation of a 'New Incoming Connection' using a modem, but I can't find any programmatic way to do this using commands or code.
I’ve tried using the rasdial and rasphone commands, but they only manage the caller side of the connection. I also know that the RRAS (Routing and Remote Access) service needs to be started but my main issue is configuring the incoming connection settings, such as selecting my modem and setting the IP settings. Regarding the netsh and netstat commands, I couldn't find any network interface related to incoming connections. I’m also unclear about what happens in the system when I configure an incoming connection. I was hoping to find a command to automate this process, but I haven’t found anything that works.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
